# Is $\{\}\;, \{\{\}\}\;\;,\{\{\{\}\}\}$ is an empty set or not?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Which of the following sets are equivalent to the empty set?
>
> 1. $\{\}$
> 2. $\{\{\}\}$
> 3. $\{\{\{\}\}\}$

**My Opinion:** The first is the empty set because it contains no elements. The second and third sets are not the empty set because each contains an empty set.

Comment: Can you define each of them?  Remember that $\{ \varnothing \} \ne \varnothing$.  Also, $\varnothing \notin \{ \{ \varnothing \} \}$ (you mentioned that the third set contains the empty set)

Comment: If by double brackets you mean $\{ \} = \emptyset$, then you're correct. The second two are not empty and the first one is.

Answer (score 19):

Yes. The first set is the **only** empty set. To convince yourself that the other two are not empty sets, try to answer these two questions:

$1$. Is a bag containing an empty bag empty?

$2$. Is a bag containing a bag, that contains an empty bag, empty?